# Information on 50% drop in spam starting Christmas 2010

Tags: spam

Has anybody who administers email servers or spam filtering noticed that in last couple of weeks the spam volume has dropped significantly? Is there a chart provided by one of the major spam filtering companies?

**Edit:** Based on our internal stats, although it varies, on the two weeks starting the day after Christmas (Sunday), spam seems to be coming in about half as much as it did before Christmas.

Comment: While I have certainly noticed that drop I don't see how this is relevant to SF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working in CERT team in one telco company in Europe. We are observing about 50% less tickets from spamtraps complaining about customers sending spam. Reports from external sources also confirm this trent.

Comment: This probably the same drop we are noticing (we would be one of the spamtraps)

Answer (score 2):

Spam has dropped significantly worldwide because of the elimination of one of the main organisations causing spam - aptly called Spamit.

You can find some graphs at [Net Security](http://www.net-security.org/secworld.php?id=10381) provided by an internet security company called Commtouch.  Unfortunately for all those of us who have to maintain email systems, these reduced levels are not expected to stay low for long, as another company will doubtlessly step up into the space that Spamit vacated.

Comment: Unfortunately from looking at internal stats, it's on the way back up again.

Comment: I am referring specifically to a much larger drop that happened around Christmas. This link is probably not the same thing as I am talking about.